# Splitting up React-Native code: General Practices

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, code-structure

I am building a React-Native app social media application, and I am really struggling with fitting everything together.

I want to make very modular code, hopefully splitting up my JSX, my JavaScript functions, and all of my redux and redux-persist stuff (unsure how to go about using these as well and where to split up using action creators and just normal functions.) However, I am really just unsure of a good file structure to maintain all of these things properly.

I am open to any suggestions and would really appreciate some good sample code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Axios default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995863/what-is-axios-default-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

> Below image is the folder structure to follow for a React and react-native app. Please let me know if you need in-depth detail of the structure shared in image

[image: Folder structure to follow for a React and react-native app]